# Do need to databind in gridview?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, data-binding

```
 If dt_grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dt_grid.DataSource = dt_grid
 Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found Data")
 End If
```

I know that if get datatable  in gridview.datasource,ever write gridview.Databind.But I found coding of my friend. He write only get datatable in `gridview.datasource` but no write gridview.dataBind. Therefore, his coding is not error. Why? Don't need to dataBind?

Comment: Please add some Code to your Question. As you written, your question is very hard to understand

Comment: Of course! @ZarNge. Read dataBinding article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your friend is not using the DataSourceID property?

Here is the difference from MSDN:

> When the DataSourceID property is set (instead of the DataSource property), the data-bound control automatically binds to the data source control at run time.

Please take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) and [this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasourceid.aspx#Y300)

Hope it helped.

I took the time to do a small example to demonstrate that you need to call DataBind() on a normal asp.net gridview in order to render its data.

If your friend is not calling this, I am guessing that he is binding the grid to a data source in the .aspx code (to a SQLDatasource, on even an ObjectDataSource) and he is modifying that datasource in the code.

Please take a look at the following example:

The default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewDemo._Default" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
</form>
```

The codebehind for the page: (it is in C# but I think it is relevant to VB as well)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewDemo
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Entity
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Entity> source = new List<Entity>() { new Entity() { ID = 1, Name = "First" }, new Entity() { ID = 2, Name = "Second" } };
            GridView1.DataSource = source;
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
            // if you comment this line and run, the gridview is not rendered
        }


    }
}
```

Let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: my friend is not using the DataSourceId property.You refer DatasourceID is sqlDatasourceID or something??